# The cheapest (in terms of efforts) way to mount mic stand to a table with slanted edges

Tags: table

I bought a microphone table stand and only after that I've realized that the edges of my (*only one and beloved*) IKEA table aren’t flat enough.

I've tried different options but predictably have failed.

[image]

[image]

**Question:** Is there's something I can do to have a good enough solution to mount somehow this exact stand to this particular table?

**UPD:** I've implemented @willk's solutions, so I'm accepting it (though both answers are awesome). Works like charm!

[image]

Comment: `I've tried different options` ... what options? ... try inserting a board between the underside of the tabletop and clamp

Comment: @jsotola I've tried to put a couple of layers of carton underside and I've tried to install it under a subtle angle.

Comment: Dang that looks good!  You used clamps that match the mike stand and a very handsome board.  It looks like something that came with the stand.  Thank you very much for posting the image.  ...sniff... my baby is all grown up....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Build out the edge with a clamped on board.**

For this you will need a pair of deep C clamps and a board.  Here is what I found in the garage.   Clamps must be deeper than your microphone stand clamp.  Board should be wide; probably wider than this one.

[image: clamps and board]

Clamp the board to the underside of your table.  Here I used the brush drawer to stand in for your table edge.

[image: clamps and board]

Your clamps will be off to either side and not interfere with your microphone stand clamp in the middle.  You will be out the cost of clamps, but these clamps will be useful for many years after you are done with the microphone and stand.  You will not need to put screws into your table.

Put some cardboard under the clamps so you don't mar the tabletop.

Final result is the effectively the same as [@jsotola solution](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/218079/the-cheapest-in-terms-of-efforts-way-to-mount-mic-stand-to-a-table-with-slante/218082#218082).  Downside is the expense of clamps.  Upside is no screws or modification to table itself.

Comment: this is even a better idea than mine ... turn the clamps upside down so that they are low profile ... clamp the microphone stand to the board ... that way the microphone stand is completely off the table

Comment: Updated the question with a photo of your solution implementation - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

A piece of a board between the clamp and the tabletop should work.

If not sturdy, then drill a hole in the clamp arm and use a screw to secure the end of the board.

You could also attach the board to the underside of the table with doublesided tape.

If you cannot find wood, then get a cheap plastic cutting board meant for kitchen use.

[image]

Another possibility, but not cheapest is to drill a cable hole, and pass the clamp through the hole.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, this looks like a viable solution!

Comment: Wood screwed to table is good idea.  No need to drill steel.